# Pandas | Empty plot using pandas.df.plot()?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, plot

I'm trying to implement a gradient descent implementation in python, however, I'm not able to display the data with pandas. I would expect the data to be displayed with 'release_date' as the x-axis and 'budget' as the y-axis.
In my code below I convert the date to a Series of float64 in order to have a numeric value as the date.

```
Python 3.5.2 (default, Aug 18 2017, 17:48:00) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import numpy
>>> import pandas
>>> import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
>>> movieData = pandas.read_csv('tmdb_5000_movies.csv', usecols = ['budget', 'release_date'])
>>> movieData['release_date'] = pandas.to_datetime(movieData['release_date'], format='%Y-%m-%d')
>>> movieData['release_date'] = movieData['release_date'].dt.year
>>> movieData = movieData.sort_values(['release_date'], ascending = True)
>>> movieData.plot('release_date', 'budget')
<matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot object at 0x7f985fa3e470>
>>> plt.show()

>>> 
>>> movieData.head()
        budget  release_date
4592    385907        1916.0
4661    245000        1925.0
2638  92620000        1927.0
4594    379000        1929.0
4457         0        1929.0
>>>
```

This is my output:
[image]

Why is this returning an empty plot?

Comment: What is `print (df.budget.dtype)` ?

Comment: >>> movieData.budget.dtype
dtype('int64')

Comment: Hmmm, then maybe too much data and most data are too low (very close axix x). Is possible filter out higher data and then try plot?

Comment: Just plotted the first rows .head(), it's showing correctly. The issue probably occurs because of what you said, have too many variables ~5000 with a large difference between budgets 0 ~  92620000

Comment: Yes, exactly. so the best is filter data some way and then plot.